# Find volume of solid bounded by $z=x+y,(x^2+y^2)^2=2xy,z=0,(x>0,y>0)$

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, surface-integrals

Moving into polar coordinates find volume of solid bounded by given surfaces.

$z=x+y,(x^2+y^2)^2=2xy,z=0,(x>0,y>0)$

Moving into polar coordinates we get. $z=r(cos\phi+sin\phi),r^2=sin(2\phi),z=0$

$r(cos\phi+sin\phi)=0$ $\to$ $r=0$ or $\phi=\frac{3\pi}{4}$

But I am having trouble how to set up bounds for $r$ and $\phi.$ [image]

Comment: Do you know the answer? I got $\pi/8$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes that is the answer.

Comment: I would love to post the answer, but someone has beaten me.

Answer (score 2):

Set up the volume integration as follows
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}}z \ rdr d\phi= \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\sqrt{\sin 2\phi}}(\sin \phi+\cos \phi) r^2dr d\phi= \frac\pi8
$$

Comment: (+1) One minute. I only needed one more minute.

Comment: @Quanto why is upper bound for $\phi$ $\frac{\pi}{2}?$

Comment: @unit1991 $r^2=\sin 2\phi =0$ for $\phi =0, \pi/2$.

Comment: @Quanto Sorry for asking many questions but we have also that $\phi=\frac{3\pi}{4}?$

Comment: @unit1991 - note that the region for the cylindrical integration is determined by $r^2= \sin2\phi$, not by $z = r(\sin \phi +\cos\phi$